# Pandoc: Reference loc file in latex template

Tags: pandoc

Might be more of a Pandoc question than a TeX question but I hope you can help anyway. Following situation:

I'm on Windows and in `%AppData%\Roaming\pandoc\templates` I have 2 files:

- `absender.lco`
- `brief.latex`

`brief.latex` looks basically like this:

```
\documentclass[
absender,
paper=a4,
version=last,
fontsize=11pt,
DIV=13,
BCOR=0mm]{scrlttr2}

% ...

\LoadLetterOption{absender}

% ...
```

`absender.lco`:

```
\ProvidesFile{absender.lco}[letter-class-option file]

% ...
```

---

My problem is the following: When I run

```
$ pandoc x.md -o x.pdf --template=brief
```

somewhere else on the system (with a correct `x.md`) I get the following response:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Class scrlttr2 Error: Letter-Class-Option file `absender.lco' not found.

See the scrlttr2 class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.32 \LoadLetterOption{absender}
```

It did work, when I had both files mentioned earlier in the same directory where my `x.md` is - but as you might understand I don't want to copy them to every directory where I use them (I mean, that's the way templates should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `pandoc` but `latex` which is looking for `absender.lco`. And `latex` does not look into `%AppData%\Roaming\pandoc\templates`. Instead, you could but the file into the local `TEXMF` provided by your TeX distirbution tree somewhere below `tex/latex`.

Comment: Great. I didn't know of `texmf` before. For the record: I created the structure: `%userprofile%\texmf\tex\latex`, moved my `absender.lco` to there and it worked.